# Parallelism in Apache Storm with one worker node

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to Parallelize my topology using Apache Storm but it gives me `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` error on worker nodes if I increased the number of workers>1. It works fine with 1 worker and in local cluster. I want a way to parallelize my topology and measure the different parameters like throughput, latency, emit rate etc. using one worker node only.

Comment: If you want help solving the ConcurrentModificationException, you should post your Storm version, describe what your topology is doing and probably also post the stack trace you're getting.

Comment: Ok so my storm version is 1.1.1. My topology is performing naive bayes classification for a text file containing text with class. So spout is reading the data from text file and emit tuples "text" and "class". Next is Instance bolt which collects the tuples and turns them into instance object for weka and moa. Next bolt take string instances and turns them into word vectors. Next bolt use the bayes classifier and then write it to a file. So I am getting concurrent modification exception in Instance bolt. My error stack trace is as follows:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:495) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
 at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:460) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
 at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:73) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
 at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_loop_STAR_$fn__4482.invoke(disruptor.clj:83) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]

Comment: This is a rethrow of a different exception. Please recheck the log, there's likely a "Caused by:" below the snippet you posted.

Comment: Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:770) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128) ~[?:1.8.0_171]

Comment: at org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.write(SerializableSerializer.java:38) ~[storm-core-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
 at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
 at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
 at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace you posted, it looks like Kryo is trying to serialize an ArrayList and hitting a ConcurrentModificationException. I would look for any place you emit an ArrayList and make sure that you don't modify it after you've passed it to `OutputCollector.emit`.

Likely the reason you're not seeing this issue when you only have one worker is that Storm only serializes emitted objects when they need to be sent to a different worker.

Comment: Ok so you are saying that in the bolt after emitting, tuple should not be modified. A snippet of my Bolt is shown below:
               String sentence = input.getStringByField("text");
  String label = input.getStringByField("class");
 
  //Turn it into an instance
  Instance inst = new DenseInstance(2);
  
  inst.setDataset(INST_HEADERS);
  
  inst.setValue(0, sentence);
  
  if(label.contains("sports/enter")){
        
   inst.setClassValue(1);
   
  }else{
   
   inst.setClassValue(0);
  }

  _collector.emit(new Values(inst));
  _collector.ack(input);

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't see an obvious issue with your snippet, but somewhere you're likely emitting a List that you're then modifying.

Comment: I checked the code and I found that I was passing a list in next bolt with same name as in instance bolt but with modification. Thatswhy it was giving this error.. Thanks Stig Rohde for your kind suggestions.